# How to use plain toastr.js with angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, toastr

What the steps to followed to setup and use toastr with angular 2 :
https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

I am using Angular 2 + Typescript + Webpack + npm combination.

I tried doing an `npm install toastr` and importing it in my project followed by `declare var toastr :any;` None of this helped

Please guide

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript requires definition file to use JS and toastr library doesn't have it.

However, you can use [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to get d.ts file.

`typings install dt~toastr --global --save`

If needed add also definition file for JQuery.

Now you can use toastr in your component and remember to import css for example in vendor.ts.

`import * as toastr from 'toastr';`

`toastr.error('Title', 'Error message');`

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out